# Error "BIND VARIABLE "A" NOT DECLARED" when running PL/SQL block

Tags: plsql

When running the following code in Oracle 10g (pl/sql)

```
DECLARE 
    A NUMBER;
    B NUMBER;
BEGIN:
     A:=&N;
     B:=&M;
 IF (A>B)
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE MAXIMUM OF TWO NUMBER IS:' || TO_CHAR(A));
 ELSE 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THE MAXIMUM OF TWO NUMBERS IS:' || TO_CHAR(B));
 END IF;
END;
```

I get the error 'BIND VARIABLE "A" NOT DECLARED' and I don't know why.  What is causing this?

Comment: Can you mention the ORA error number ?

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code.

The first problem is that there should be no colon after `BEGIN`.  What you've written is being interpreted by Oracle as `BEGIN :A := ...`, and that should explain why you're getting an error about bind variable `A`.

The second problem is with the line `IF (A>B)`.  You need to add a `THEN` to the end.

Incidentally, you can use `GREATEST(A, B)` to return the larger of two numbers.